# Projecting an N-dimensional array to 1-d

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have an n-dimensional array I'd like to display in a table. Something like this:

```
@data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
@dimensions = [{:name => "speed", :values => [0..20,20..40,40..60]}, 
              {:name => "distance", :values => [0..50, 50..100, 100..150]}]
```

And I'd like the table to end up looking like this:

```
speed  | distance | count
0..20  | 0..50    | 1
0..20  | 50..100  | 2
0..20  | 100..150 | 3
20..40 | 0..50    | 4
20..40 | 50..100  | 5
20..40 | 100..150 | 6
40..60 | 0..50    | 7
40..60 | 50..100  | 8
40..60 | 100..150 | 9
```

Is there a pretty way to pull this off? I have a working solution that I'm actually kind of proud of; this post is a bit humble-brag. However, it does feel overly complicated, and there's no way I or anyone else is going to understand what's going on later.

```
[nil].product(*@dimensions.map do |d|
   (0...d[:values].size).to_a
end).map(&:compact).map(&:flatten).each do |data_idxs|
   row = data_idxs.each_with_index.map{|data_idx, dim_idx|
     @dimensions[dim_idx][:values][data_idx]
   }
   row << data_idxs.inject(@data){|data, idx| data[idx]}
   puts row.join(" |\t ")
end
```

Comment: Bent, I edited my solution to offer some comments on yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
first, *rest = @dimensions.map {|d| d[:values]}
puts first
  .product(*rest)
  .transpose
  .push(@data.flatten)
  .transpose
  .map {|row| row.map {|cell| cell.to_s.ljust 10}.join '|' }
  .join("\n")
```

Comment: Wow! That's really nice, thank you. I didn't know about the `first, rest` syntax, nor ljust, and the transpose/flatten is brilliant. I'm going to s/rest/\*rest/g to make this work in 1.8.7/1.9.4. If it worked in some other version, feel free to revert.

Answer (score 1):

Bent, let me first offer a few comments on your solution.  (Then I will offer an alternative approach that also uses `Array#product`.)  Here is your code, formatted to expose the structure:

```
[nil].product(*@dimensions.map { |d| (0...d[:values].size).to_a })
.map(&:compact)
.map(&:flatten)
.each do |data_idxs|
  row = data_idxs.each_with_index.map
    { |data_idx, dim_idx| @dimensions[dim_idx][:values][data_idx] }
  row << data_idxs.inject(@data) { |data, idx| data[idx] }
  puts row.join(" |\t ")
end
```

- I find it very confusing, in part because of your reluctance to define intermediate variables.  I would first compute `product`'s argument and assign it to a variable `x`.  I say `x` because it's hard to come up with a good name for it.  I would then assign the results of `product` to another variable, like so: `y = x.shift.product(x)` or (if you don't want `x` modified) `y = x.first.product(x[1..-1)`.  This avoids the need for `compact` and `flatten`.
- I find the choice of variable names confusing.  The root of the problem is that `@dimensions` and `@data` both begin with `d`!  This problem would be diminished greatly if you simply used, say, `@vals` instead of `@data`.
- It would be more idiomatic to write `data_idxs.each_with_index.map` as `data_idxs.map.with_index`.
- Lastly, but most important, is your decision to use indices rather than the values themselves.  **Don't do that.  Just don't do that.**  Not only is this unnecessary, but it makes your code so complex that figuring it out is time-consuming and headache-producing.

Consider how easy it is to manipulate the data without any reference to indices:

```
vals = @dimensions.map {|h| h.values }
  # [["speed",    [0..20, 20..40,  40..60  ],
  #  ["distance", [0..50, 50..100, 100..150]]
attributes = vals.map(&:shift)
  #  ["speed", "distance"] 
  # vals => [[[0..20, 20..40, 40..60]],[[0..50, 50..100, 100..150]]] 
vals = vals.flatten(1).map {|a| a.map(&:to_s)}
  # [["0..20", "20..40", "40..60"],["0..50", "50..100", "100..150"]] 
rows = vals.first.product(*vals[1..-1]).zip(@data.flatten).map { |a,d| a << d }
  # [["0..20", "0..50",  1],["0..20", "50..100",  2],["0..20", "100..150",  3],
  #  ["20..40", "0..50", 4],["20..40", "50..100", 5],["20..40", "100..150", 6],
  #  ["40..60", "0..50", 7],["40..60", "50..100", 8],["40..60", "100..150", 9]]
```

I would address the problem in such a way that you could have any number of attributes (i.e., "speed", "distance",...) and the formatting would dictated by the data:

```
V_DIVIDER = ' | '
COUNT = 'count'

attributes = @dimensions.map {|h| h[:name]}   
sd = @dimensions.map { |h| h[:values].map(&:to_s) }
fmt = sd.zip(attributes)
        .map(&:flatten)
        .map {|a| a.map(&:size)}
        .map {|a| "%-#{a.max}s" }   
attributes.zip(fmt).each { |a,f| print f % a + V_DIVIDER }
puts COUNT

prod = (sd.shift).product(*sd)
flat_data = @data.flatten
until flat_data.empty? do
  prod.shift.zip(fmt).each { |d,f| print f % d + V_DIVIDER }
  puts (flat_data.shift)
end
```

If

```
@dimensions = [{:name => "speed",    :values => [0..20,20..40,40..60]      }, 
               {:name => "volume",   :values => [0..30, 30..100, 100..1000]},
               {:name => "distance", :values => [0..50, 50..100, 100..150] }]
```

this is displayed:

```
speed  | volume    | distance | count
0..20  | 0..30     | 0..50    | 1
0..20  | 0..30     | 50..100  | 2
0..20  | 0..30     | 100..150 | 3
0..20  | 30..100   | 0..50    | 4
0..20  | 30..100   | 50..100  | 5
0..20  | 30..100   | 100..150 | 6
0..20  | 100..1000 | 0..50    | 7
0..20  | 100..1000 | 50..100  | 8
0..20  | 100..1000 | 100..150 | 9
```

It works as follows (with the original value of `@dimensions`, having just the two attributes, "speed" and "distance"):

`Attributes` is a list of the attributes.  Being an array, it maintains their order:

```
attributes = @dimensions.map {|h| h[:name]}
  # => ["speed", "distance"]
```

We pull out the ranges from `@dimensions` and convert them to strings:

```
sd = @dimensions.map { |h| h[:values].map(&:to_s) }
  # => [["0..20", "20..40", "40..60"], ["0..50", "50..100", "100..150"]]
```

Next we compute the string formating for all columns but the last:

```
fmt = sd.zip(attributes)
        .map(&:flatten)
        .map {|a| a.map(&:size)}
        .map {|a| "%-#{a.max}s" }
  # => ["%-6s", "%-8s"]
```

Here

```
sd.zip(attributes)
  # => [[["0..20", "20..40", "40..60"],    "speed"   ],
  #     [["0..50", "50..100", "100..150"], "distance"]]
```

`8` in `"%-8s"` equals the maximum of the length of the column label, `distance` (8) and the length of the longest string representation of a `distance` range (also 8, for `"100..150"`). The `-` in the formatting string left-adjusts the strings.

We can now print the header:

```
attributes.zip(fmt).each { |a,f| print f % a + V_DIVIDER }
puts COUNT
speed  | distance | count
```

To print the remaining lines, we construct an array containing the contents of the first two columns.  Each element of the array corresponds to a row of the table:

```
prod = (sd.shift).product(*sd)
  # => ["0..20", "20..40", "40..60"].product(*[["0..50", "50..100", "100..150"]]) 
  # => ["0..20", "20..40", "40..60"].product(["0..50", "50..100", "100..150"]) 

  # => [["0..20", "0..50"], ["0..20", "50..100"],  ["0..20", "100..150"],
  #    ["20..40", "0..50"], ["20..40", "50..100"], ["20..40", "100..150"],
  #    ["40..60", "0..50"], ["40..60", "50..100"], ["40..60", "100..150"]]
```

We need to flaten @data:

```
flat_data = @data.flatten
  # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The first time through the `until do` loop,

```
r1 = prod.shift
  # => ["0..20", "0..50"]
  # prod now => [["0..20", "50..100"],...,["40..60", "100..150"]] 
r2 = r1.zip(fmt)
  # => [["0..20", "%-6s"], ["0..50", "%-8s"]]
r2.each { |d,f| print f % d + V_DIVIDER }
0..20  | 0..50    | 
puts (flat_data.shift)
0..20  | 0..50    | 1
  # flat_data now => [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: `(sd.shift).product(*sd)` Hey that's pretty clever. The %-Ns format is a good trick too, and the answer in general is way simpler than my version. Thanks for the reply!